# at hover append span one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my html:

```
  <ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li class='fade'>Chips</li>
    <li class='fade'>Socks</li>
  </ul>
```

this is my js function:-

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
  },
  function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
  }
);
```

i want to this type of output:-

```
<ul>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Bread</li>
        <li class='fade'>Chips</li>
        <li class='fade'>Socks</li>
<span> ***</span>
      </ul>
```

here i am try to append one span in mouse hover on li.
its work perfect.
but i want to append only one time after last li.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found the example on the **[jQuery api manual](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**, isn't this what you want?

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
  },
  function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
  }
);
```

Or you don't want to remove the span when mouse leave, and just want to append one span:

```
$("li").hover(function () {
  if ($(this).find('span').length == 0) {
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
  }
});
```

Comment: @JackPhp What do you mean? Could you post your expected result html?

Comment: @JackPhp Change `$(this)` to `$('ul')`, but it's wired to have a `span` inside `ul`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `one`:

```
$("li").one("hover", function () {
   $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: @JackPhp - it will work on the li yes and only append it one time.

Comment: @DarrenDavies do you not have to pass an event as the first parameter?

Comment: @billyonecan - of course yes, dave has pointed that out also.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check first if the span already exists. Remember that 'hover' can take two functions if you want to remove the span after the mouse leaves. This is the equivalent to mouseover and mouseleave combined.

```
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
      $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
    }
  });
```

References: [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/), [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Answer (score 0):

Use modern JS!

```
const lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
let span;
for (const li of lis) {
    li.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        // Do something cool
        if (!span) {
             span = document.createElement("span");
             span.innerText = " ***";
             li.parentElement.append(span);
        }
    }, {once : true}); // (optional) This will make it fire only once for each li
                       // You could add one "once" listener to just the ul as well
}
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once), [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)

Comment: if you have 10000000 <li> this will add 10000000 event listeners

Comment: Sure, no different than the other jQuery solutions. Function doesn't have to be declared inline. If you are working with that many links, this solution isn't for you. Key, however, is `once`

Comment: I see sry I am unable to remove the down vote without an edit!